# How to implement busy signal with async library?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm using Boost.Asio but this question should cover any async framework.

I have a class that sends and receives data over a network. I'd like to give my users read and write methods and a is_busy() for them to check when data is available. Right now I have the completion handler of the write method fire a background thread that reads and returns to a future while the read() method reads from that future. The write method sets a bool to true and the read thread sets it to false when data is returned.

Is there a better way? If I understand it correctly using Asio I'd need completion handlers but no way to tell my users that data hasn't arrived yet without blocking.

**Update**

Code sample:

```
void Socket::write(const vector<byte> input) {
  busy_ = true;
  read_buffer_.clear();
  socket_->async_write_some(asio::buffer(input), [&](const std::error_code ec, const size_t length) {
    if (ec && ec != asio::error::operation_aborted) {
      throw std::system_error(ec);
    }
    if (ec == asio::error::operation_aborted) {
      return;
    }
    read_f = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
        socket_->async_read_some(asio::null_buffers(), [&](const std::error_code ec, const size_t length) {
           if (ec && ec != asio::error::operation_aborted) {
             throw std::system_error(ec);
           }
           if (ec == asio::error::operation_aborted) {
             return;
           }
          read_buffer_.resize(socket_->available());
          socket_->read_some(asio::buffer(read_buffer_));
          busy_ = false;
         });
        unsigned long a = service_.run();
        service_.reset();
        busy_ = false;
        return a;
      });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code for reading and writing from the future.

Comment: @stark Added code sample.

Comment: A coroutine seems to be the simpler approach here.

Comment: Do you know that GCC implementation of async spawns a new thread for each task, right?

Comment: I've abandoned this design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using `asio::socket_base::bytes_readable` to check if there is data in the socket ready to be read and if the number of bytes is 0 I just sleep for a certain amount of microseconds.